# Atom editor - convert line endings to UNIX

Tags: atom-editor

I need to convert the line endings of some mock data into Unix format. I'm using Atom editor on Win 7.

Looking online, I found an Atom package to convert line endings, but the package said it is deprecated since Atom now has this as a standard feature.

I cannot find any such standard feature in Atom - and Atom's documentation doesn't even know what line-ending conversion is.

'About Atom' tells me Atom is up-to-date with v.1.23.3

This, to me, seems a paradox.

(And no, I cannot just use Notepad++.)

I've looked around at a lot of solutions, but have not found one that will actually work.

Answer (score 21):

The built in *line-ending-selector* package supports this use case: https://atom.io/packages/line-ending-selector

The package's documentation describes how to do this:

> You can click the line ending in the status-bar to open a modal with the line ending options. Selecting a different line ending will change each line of the file in the active editor.

[image: Click]

[image: Change Line Ending]

If you prefer to use the keyboard, you can also open the command palette (`cmd-shift-p` on macOS), type *Convert* and then use the *Line Ending Selector: Convert to LF* and *Line Ending Selector: Convert to CRLF* commands from there.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Preferences under Atom menu. Uner the settings window, go to Packages. In packages search on line-ending-selector. This reveals a core package that is loaded with Atom. Scroll down the line-ending-selector page and you see the header Settings. Below that you can choose the default line endings. You can choose LF, CNTL-LF, or OS. Set this to the value you want.